# pydev debugger fails on launch but code runs fine

Tags: pydev, liclipse

When I launch the pydev debugger with LiClipse (latest versions of both) I get a "KeyError:" exception.

I have ensured that the workspace folder has the proper permissions. I get this problem even if I run LiClipse in Administrator mode.

I expect to be able to debug my python code. My actual results are the following errors:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 15388)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.2.4\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261609\pysrc\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 487, in _original_file_to_client
    return cache[filename]
KeyError: 'c:\\users\\xyz\\my documents\\liclipse workspace\\xyzjirabot\\xyzjirabot.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.2.4\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261609\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_net_command_factory_xml.py", line 197, in make_thread_stack_str
    py_db, curr_frame, frame_id_to_lineno
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.2.4\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261609\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_net_command_factory_xml.py", line 170, in _iter_visible_frames_info
    filename_in_utf8 = pydevd_file_utils.norm_file_to_client(abs_path_real_path_and_base[0])
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.2.4\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261609\pysrc\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 489, in _original_file_to_client
    translated = _path_to_expected_str(get_path_with_real_case(_AbsFile(filename)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.2.4\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261609\pysrc\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 196, in _get_path_with_real_case
    return _resolve_listing(drive, iter(parts))
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 5.2.4\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.2.1.201904261609\pysrc\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 159, in _resolve_listing
    dir_contents = cache[resolved_lower] = os.listdir(resolved)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\xyz\\My Documents'
```

Answer (score 1):

While I was posting this question I noticed that there is a capitalization difference with the file name being used as the key and the actual file path. I moved the workspace to the root of my C Drive and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the spaces in the filename. I moved it to \Users\kieveli\Source\LiClipseWorkspace\ and everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - Path was set to "..\My Documents" instead of just "..\Documents". Changing the workspace to another directory fixed the problem