# Using VS Code to debug python files. Exception thrown on breakpoint and breakpoint is ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

Tried with multiple different python files. Every time I try to use the debugger in vs code and set breakpoints the breakpoint gets ignored and exception gets raised and the script continues on. I've been googling and tinkering for over 2 hours and can't seem to figure out what's going on here. Tried rebooting PC, running vs code as admin, uninstall/reinstall the python extension for vs code. Tried to dig into the files mentioned in the traceback and pinpointed the function that seems to be raising the exception but I can't figure out where it's being called from or why it's raising the exception. I'm still new-ish to Python. Debugging works properly on my laptop but for whatever reason my desktop is having this issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 529, in _original_file_to_client
    return cache[filename]
KeyError: 'c:\\users\\joel\\local settings\\application data\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\runpy.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 330, in _on_run
    self.process_net_command_json(self.py_db, json_contents)
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command_json.py", line 190, in process_net_command_json    
    cmd = on_request(py_db, request)
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command_json.py", line 771, in on_stacktrace_request       
    self.api.request_stack(py_db, request.seq, thread_id, fmt=fmt, start_frame=start_frame, levels=levels)
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_api.py", line 214, in request_stack
    if internal_get_thread_stack.can_be_executed_by(get_current_thread_id(threading.current_thread())):
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 661, in can_be_executed_by
    py_db, self.seq, self.thread_id, frame, self._fmt, must_be_suspended=not timed_out, start_frame=self._start_frame, levels=self._levels)
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_net_command_factory_json.py", line 213, in make_get_thread_stack_message
    py_db, frames_list
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_net_command_factory_xml.py", line 175, in _iter_visible_frames_info    
    new_filename_in_utf8, applied_mapping = pydevd_file_utils.norm_file_to_client(filename_in_utf8)
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 531, in _original_file_to_client
    translated = _path_to_expected_str(get_path_with_real_case(_AbsFile(filename)))
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 221, in _get_path_with_real_case
    return _resolve_listing(drive, iter(parts))
  File "c:\Users\Joel\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 184, in _resolve_listing
    dir_contents = cache[resolved_lower] = os.listdir(resolved)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Joel\\Local Settings'
```

So I get this traceback every time a breakpoint is hit. Taking a peek at the "_original_file_to_client" function in "pydevd_file_utils.py" we get this:

```
def _original_file_to_client(filename, cache={}):
    try:
        return cache[filename]
    except KeyError:
        translated = _path_to_expected_str(get_path_with_real_case(_AbsFile(filename)))
        cache[filename] = (translated, False)
    return cache[filename]
```

I wasn't able to figure out where this function was being called from or what the expected output was supposed to be. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Forgot to mention I'm using Windows 10 if it wasn't obvious from the trace

Comment: did you try to uncheck "Raise Exceptions" and "Uncaught Exceptions" under "Breakpoints"? The only breakpoints are the ones that you set in the script.

Comment: @liamsuma Just tried that. Still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281257/pydev-debugger-fails-on-launch-but-code-runs-fine) is a similar question. The spaces in the filename cause this problem:
"Local Settings", "application data"

Comment: I thought that might be the issue too but when I went to check it out I don't even have a "Local Settings" folder in my user folder. It's not a valid directory.

Comment: It looks like there are some problems with your interpreter. Can you select the virtual environment or reinstall the global python?